# How to send hex with Python

Tags: python, linux, hex, raspberry-pi

I want to send a hex code from my Raspberry Pi to the connected Servo Drive. I have a RS 485 Shield from Link Sprite for the Communication.
The Shield works because I get an answer in Python shell. My Question is how can I send `0111050200013F0804` to my Servo Drive?

The code I have so far is

```
import serial
port = "/dev/ttyAMAO"
usart = serial.Serial (port,4800)
usart.flushInput()
usart.write("0111050200013F0804")
```

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my code: import serial ... port = "/dev/ttyAMAO"... usart = serial.Serial (port,4800) ... usart.flushInput() ... usart.write("0111050200013F0804") ... is for the next line i dont can do it here.

Comment: What is the Servo Drive that you are using? Can you edit your question to include the name of the Servo Drive and preferably a link to the documentation for it?

Comment: Do you need to send the *text* or the *hex digits*?

Comment: I have a Servo Form Linmot a c1200. I want to send the Hex digits. With this digits the Servo knows what he must do. In this case it is the Homing. Tomorrow i will send you the manual.

Comment: Hello, i have the C1100 Servo Sorry. Here is the Link for the User Manual.   http://www.linmot.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/software-firmware/servo-drives/linmot-talk-6/Usermanual_LinRS_e_recent.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Hex is just a way of displaying binary information in a more concise way. Each group of 4 bits is represented by alphanumeric digit ranging from `0` to `F`. Therefore if you wanted to represent the following binary `101100011111` in hex, it would be `B1F`. For more see [this page on code project.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4069/Learning-Binary-and-Hexadecimal)

## Python 3

In Python 3 byte objects are different to strings. The first thing that needs to be done is to convert the hex in to a byte object which then can be written on the serial port.

```
import serial
port = "/dev/ttyAMAO"
usart = serial.Serial (port,4800)
message_bytes = bytes.fromhex("0111050200013F0804")
usart.write(message_bytes)
```

## Python 2

In Python 2 strings and bytes are the same thing. However you still need to convert the hex text into its equivalent bytes. This can be done using the `decode("hex")` on a string.

```
import serial
port = "/dev/ttyAMAO"
usart = serial.Serial (port,4800)
message_bytes = "0111050200013F0804".decode("hex")
usart.write(message_bytes)
```